# make a hidden angular table row still searchable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on a job posting site. my search results show up in a ng-repeat. there are many properties to each job. i only want to show 3 of them in the search results page and all of them in the job detail page. how can i search for jobs using all of the properties of jobs and still only display 3 on the search view?

```
<tr ng-repeat="job in jobArray  | filter: search | orderBy:mySortFunction"> 
                        <td><a ng-click='getJob(job.jobId)'>{{job.jobTitle}}</a></td>
                        <td>{{job.description}}</td>
                        <td>{{job.dateCreated}}</td>
                        <td ng-hide="true">{{job.startDate}}</td>
                        <td ng-hide="true">{{job.jobId}}</td>
                        <td ng-hide="true">{{job.yearsExperience}}</td>
                        <td ng-hide="true">{{job.requiredProgrammingSkills}}</td>
                        <td ng-hide="true">{{job.requiredEducationSkills}}</td>
                        <td ng-hide="true">{{job.salaryMin}}</td>
                        <td ng-hide="true">{{job.salaryMax}}</td>
```

I want to only display the Jobtitle, JobDescription and dateCreated
thank you

Comment: What seems to be the problem? The filtering (`filter:search`) is not related to what properties are displayed. You can safely remove the hidden `td` element. Which jobs are displayed has only to do with the variable `search`. Could you post its value?

Comment: not sure if i explained it correctly. i am trying to search all the properties of the job class. right now unless i display all the properties in the table like i do with jobtite, jobdescription and datecreated i can only search for the properties displayed. does this make more sense? i just want to widen my search.... let me know if you need something else. thank you!

Comment: Again, what you display has nothing to do with filtering, it is only dependent on the filter. Refer to the filter documentation at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter .

Comment: your right! sorry. thanks for the response